# plpgsql function - column name is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql, upsert

(Am using Postgres 11.5)

I've been a Postgres user for a while now and am aware of the usual ways to avoid ambiguity (e.g. naming function inputs with a prefix etc.).  But I am really struggling with `ON CONFLICT`

I have also seen this SO question [How to disambiguate a plpgsql variable name in a ON CONFLICT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47678934/4474629), but either I've misread it or it doesn't really seem to be the issue I am having.

This is my function:

```
create function foobar_data(p_category text,p_datapoint text) returns integer AS $$
BEGIN
        INSERT INTO foobar(category,datapoint,statcount) VALUES(p_category,p_datapoint,0)
        ON CONFLICT(category,datapoint) DO UPDATE
        SET statcount=statcount+1 where category=p_category and datapoint=p_datapoint;
        IF FOUND THEN
                return 1;
        ELSE
                return 0;
        END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;
```

This returns the error:

> ERROR:  column reference "statcount" is ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ambiguity is between the original and the new column value. Qualify the column with the table name for the original value and with `EXCLUDED` for the new value:

```
SET statcount=foobar.statcount+1
```

You cannot qualify the first `statcount` since that is not allowed SQL syntax (the column automatically belongs to the updated table, so there is no ambiguity).

Comment: Aah, typical !  I tried 'foobar.statcount=foobar.statcount+1` but maybe this is the syntax I need.  Will go try ....

Answer (score 2):

You need to prefix the columns on the right hand side of the assignment in the SET part (the left hand side is unambiguous):

```
INSERT INTO foobar(category,datapoint,statcount) 
VALUES(p_category,p_datapoint,0)
ON CONFLICT(category,datapoint) DO UPDATE
  SET statcount = foobar.statcount + 1 
where category = p_category 
  and datapoint = p_datapoint;
```